# How to resume last activity that was open?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I used android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" for the main activity of my application before. Now I decided to change it to the default behaviour, so I simply deleted this line from manifest. It works as expected when I install the app from Android Studio by usb connection, but when I generate signed apk and install it manually, or download from Google Play, the application works as clearTaskOnLaunch="true" is still active, it is not reverted.

I did try to add clearTaskOnLaunch="false" but that didn't work, so I have no idea how to revert this to default. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is this in the manifest or the actual xml of the the activity? If it's the manifest, you're probably using the manifest file in the `bin` folder. Make sure you change the one OUTSIDE the bin folder. Then do a Clean, and it'll build it again. Or it might just need a clean anyway to rebuild it. Just go to `Project` -> `Clean...` at the top of the toolbar. 

Actually, I'm saying this based on using Eclipse, so I'm not sure how it'd work using android studio.

Comment: This is in the manifest. I checked it and it is in the standard location as always, not in bin folder. Also clean and build didn't work unfortunately.